# How to write a regex to capture a number surrounded by other characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

```typescript
export interface ValueParserResult {
  value: number, 
  error: string
}

interface subParseResult {
  result: (string | number) [], 
  error: string
}

class ValueParser {

  parse(eq: string, values: {[key: string] : number}, level?: number) : ValueParserResult {
    const result: ValueParserResult = { value: 0, error: "" }
  
    const numberRe: RegExp = /([^|\\(||/|/\\-|-|\\*|\\*\\-|+|\\^])+([0-9.]*)([$|(|)|/|/-|-|*|*-|+|])+/g;
          
    const eqParse = eq.split(" ").join('');
    eqParse.replace(numberRe, (matched) => {
      return " ," + matched;
    })
    
    console.log(eqParse)
    return result;

  }
}

const vp = new ValueParser();
const values = {a: 22, b:-10, c: 5}

const eq = "123/456*82*(a+b/c)"

vp.parse(eq, values)
```

This captures the entire `eqParse` string and puts a space comma in front of it. I want to put the comma space before each value and not capture the strings before and after.

Comment: Please edit your question to make three things clear: Test input(s), the expected output(s) and your current attempts.

Comment: It's helpful to readers if you begin with a statement of the question, then provide one or more examples for illustration, each with the desired or expected result, then your code, then an explanation of how your code falls short. Requiring readers to try  to figure out the question by reverse-engineering faulty code wastes their time and is unlikely to generate interest in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Modified regex to capture numbers surrounded by other characters below

```
const numberRe: RegExp = /(?<=[^\d.])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^\d.])/g;
```

I (geewhizbang) posted your change [at a typescript runner](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIAU5QDO0AShIVhmMgN4BQyyAbpjgFzIhYC2ARtABpkDZNCgB7KB0JgooAOZ0AvnTqhIsRCgq98RCGQpVaIqOUpgOAChlyQ85AB9OPflACUyANoBdISLFJaVkFZVUEDDhCQjRWPAJiKBMRAAcEiCsIAEdgu3khFmxyDhovAGsIAE9chR9kDi4%20aCUhDAgmCAwAfgbXaE8OdCK9RMMLE0ZGBHEQGWQzI0tY4fSoMeMAXlpmOI4ABiFAqWQAIhPkFUmRKZm5xrcyDjJ5AFEADxTkLYB6Ky6AHg2XgAegAdAAmADofO4IQBqP5sUGQ%20HuLp-IFgqEw77yADc10YhLa1GyIxQW2ykMIKQwwDAVnOJ3ckIAVuJQFYAORc9wEyaiLLkr6C8mQsy0rRWe6kCBCKzcOBgBAACwg4M8GwAfBMBchprNxG1IRhxPIFUrVer3ITGGYwFgoCBTsgBOc4chFcq1eD%20ZMlDaBYSDYQjRATWbMkL0oHJvbHc6FhYCSIVCo6CHqExPlsQBAAO7LHDkqBWPkZ25ZuIxLY0OAcABMDaEvDYAFoAIwHfUcACs6czgpFJw7DYAzN8ACyQ3sANgAVAAOBvzqxwOG8b4IdwnVTZyFpfRRgrVm1AA):

Comment: Your code also captures square brackets, which really messes up what I'm trying to. I've tried to remove that but so far I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misunderstandings here:

- The pipe `|` is not an OR-operator when used inside a `[  ]` class, nor can you match a sequence of more than one character (like `/-`) in such a regex class. All characters inside an `[  ]` are treated as separate characters and that class matches exactly *one* of them.
- The `replace` method does not mutate the string it is called on. Moreover, strings are immutable in JavaScript. So you should assign the result of this call to your variable.

Here is a correction of the relevant part of your code:

```js
const eq = "123/456*82*(a+b/c)";
// A regex that either matches alphanumericals (and point) or non-alphanumericals (and not point):
const numberRe = /[\w.]+|[^\w.]+/g
// Use the return value of the replace call to assign it to eqParse:
const eqParse = eq.replace(/ /g, "").replace(numberRe, (matched) => {
  return ", " + matched; // I think you intended to have the comma first?
}).slice(2); // To skip the first ", "

console.log(eqParse);
```